# jQuery created table using ajax input - I want one column to be able to have the content changed by the user

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table being created using jQuery using ajax input. I want one column in the table to allow update. The table is being created and populated; however, the "item.hmpOrder" column is not able to be updated/changed (the column will not accept data).

The code is:

```
   $.each(responseJson1a, function(i, item) {
        $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(item.hmpId),
            $('<td>').text(item.hrId),
            $('<td>').text(item.hmId),
            $('<td>').text(item.hmName),
            $('<td><input type="text"/>').text(item.hmpOrder)
        ).appendTo('#selectedListTable');
    });
```

Comment: are you trying to change the text of the column or the input? also, youre not closing the `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the val on textbox first as in `$('<input type="text"/>').val(item.hmpOrder)`.

Then append the textbox as HTML on `<td>`

**Final code:**

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.hmpId),
        $('<td>').text(item.hrId),
        $('<td>').text(item.hmId),
        $('<td>').text(item.hmName),
        $('<td>').append($('<input type="text"/>').val(item.hmpOrder))
    ).appendTo('#selectedListTable');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line:

```
$('<td><input type="text"/>').text(item.hmpOrder)
```

You're attempting to create two elements at once, which isn't possible in the manner you're attempting.

To fix this, create the `td` first, then `append()` the `input` to it in a separate operation, like this:

```js
var responseJson1a = [{
  hmpId: 'hmpId01',
  hrId: 'hrId01',
  hmId: 'hmId01',
  hmName: 'hmName01',
  hmpOrder: 'hmpOrder01',
},{
  hmpId: 'hmpId02',
  hrId: 'hrId02',
  hmId: 'hmId02',
  hmName: 'hmName02',
  hmpOrder: 'hmpOrder02',
}];

$.each(responseJson1a, function(i, item) {
  $('<tr>').append(
    $('<td>').text(item.hmpId),
    $('<td>').text(item.hrId),
    $('<td>').text(item.hmId),
    $('<td>').text(item.hmName),
    $('<td>').text(item.hmpOrder).append('<input type="text" />'),
  ).appendTo('#selectedListTable');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="selectedListTable"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you. This adds an extra text area to enter data into. kgbph has the answer that allows the data displayed to be updated.